# Open sub directories with explorer in C #

Tags: c#

I'm making an application in C# whose purpose is to search and open a sub directory within a folder located on a server. But what I can do so far is just searching and open folders at the root ...

My code looks like this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;
namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
         public Form1()
         {
                 InitializeComponent();
         }
         private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
         {
         }
         private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
         {
                 string filepath = string.Format("C:\\TESTE\\{0}", textBox1.Text, SearchOption.AllDirectories);
                 System.Diagnostics.Process prc = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
                 prc.StartInfo.FileName = filepath;
                 prc.Start();
         }

}
}
```

I know I have to use a recursive function to scroll through all the folders but I am not able to fit the function, what I want is this: the user enters in the textbox the folder to search, click on the search button and then will be open with the explorer:

```
static void DirSearch(string sDir)
   {
       try
       {
           foreach (string d in Directory.GetDirectories(sDir))
           {
               foreach (string f in Directory.GetFiles(d))
               {
                   Console.WriteLine(f);
               }
               DirSearch(d);
           }
       }
       catch (System.Exception excpt)
       {
           Console.WriteLine(excpt.Message);
       }
   }
```

What do I have to change in my code to work?

Comment: Can you explain what isn't working so we don't have to guess?

Comment: Looks like infinite recursion to me. There is no exit condition in `DirSearch`.

Comment: @ReticulatedSpline: It is. At some point, there will be no Sub-Directory in `sDir`. At that point, the return-value of `GetDirectories` will be empty so the `foreach` loop will not run once. Then the recursion has ended. But the problem is still not clear.

Comment: I would guess that the directory pointed to by `filepath` doesn't exist.